# Can users edit an event profile?

Tags: civievent, joomla

I am using CiviCRM on Joomla.

I created an event so users can register and sign up for workshops. One our leaders dropped out and many people signed up for her session. I want them to choose another session before the conference so we can make sure we have enough space. I don't see where I can expose the event profile for editing.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility if you can't do what you are trying, would be to add a custom field to your system, the send out links to a profile containing that field and hence find out the participants' new preferences. It won't change the data you currently have about them.

If you are using Drupal,  then you may be able to send people to a webform that would contain the event fields they originally used when registering.